# Particle effect after the bullet

Tags: andengine

In my game, I fire a bullet from the gun along with that I generate a particle behind the bullet so that I look like fire effect after the bullet. But my problem is that the position I got from the bullet was distance in place. So basically I want to say that the bullet speed was high for that reason I got coordinate for the particle generation was far from each other like [image]

dot dot effect. But I want continuous flow of particle behind the bullet. So please provide any guidance for my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not talk about code so it's hard to give you the good advice.

Anyway it seems that your particles are spawned at each frame... and as your bullet travels very fast, each frame means a long distance between two draws.
That's where your dot-dot effect comes from imho.

You have to find a way to "interpolate" the particle generation between each frame. Instead of spawning particles at each draw, you spawn particle for this draw and those missing back to the last draw.

EDIT:
You know the position of your bullet when the frame is drawn. You also know the position of your bullet when the last frame was drawn (you have to save the position of your bullet at t-1). So you can determine the path your bullet has done, and then ask your particle generator to spawn particles along this path instead of only spawn particle while frame rendering.

Comment: Please provide more detail about you answer because I didn't understand what you basically want to say. Also if possible provide small code snippets.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer for more details.

Comment: Thank for response. I implement line drawing algorithm for each drawn frame and the trick worked for the particle and I got the same effect that I want. I also want to ask another question that I want effect create triangle after the bullet with particle. Please provide any suggestion for that.